# Proper way to compare BitmaskType with zero?

Tags: c++, c++11, bitmask, c++-concepts

According to the `BitmaskType` concept, the implementation has to assure that the following statement is well formend: (listed in §17.5.2.1.3.4)

> The value Y is set in the object X if the expression X & Y is nonzero.

where X and Y are of concept-type `BitmaskType`.

When trying the following simple code snippet with gcc 4.7 I get template deduction errors:

```
#include <future>

int main() {
    (std::launch::async & std::launch::async) != 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error: no match for 'operator!=' in '(std::launch)1 != 0'
... followed by tons of deduction errors
```

Is this a bug in gcc or am I just getting something wrong here? If yes, what is the proper way to perform this kind of check?

I already checked gcc buglist but couldn't find anything covering this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The members of `enum` classes are not meant to convert to `int` implicitly or vice versa. You can either make sure that your bitmask type is converted to `int` or use the zero value of the `enum` class. I'd think the latter is preferable:

```
(std::launch::async & std::launch::async) != std::launch()
```

(I have also added parenthesis around the bitwise `and` operation since it has higher precedence than the comparison and it doesn't really make much sense to bitwise `and` a Boolean value with a bitmask type).

The easiest way to see this is 7.2 [enum.dcl] paragraph 9:

> ... Note that this implicit enum to int conversion is not provided for a scoped enumeration: ...

This is, however, within a non-normative Example. Tracking the rules for scoped rules in the standard may require ruling out all the cases where conversions are allowed and currently don't quite fancy this exercise.

Comment: ok, thanks that looks good. Yeah, I forget to add the braces when copying in some code. Is `std::launch()` guaranteed to always fullfill the requirement mentioned above?

Comment: I'd think so. The way to chase it is to see what default initialization of enums means. I'm pretty sure that it becomes zero initialization but I haven't chased it up just right now.

Comment: This is value-initialization, not default-initialiazation, and value-initialization on scalar and enum types is always zero-initialization.

Comment: I don't think this really addresses the question. Sure, in practice implementations use enum class to implement the BitmaskType concept, but the fundamental issue is that the BitmaskType has this requirement that doesn't seem to be satisfied (nor satisfiable) by an enum class. I suppose it's up to how "nonzero" is interpreted. cppreference editors seem to also interpret it as a literal 0 integer (which afaik an enum class cannot satisfy)